# I have two externally loaded SWF files and I would like for each to recognize that the other has loaded or !loaded?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, swfloader

After loading 2 SWF files via two separate buttons, I am attempting to get one to recognize that the other is being viewed and unload. What would be the best way given the code here?

```
function matrixLoad(event:MouseEvent): void
{
if (fl_ToLoad3)
{
    fl_Proloader3 = new fl_Proloader3();
    fl_Proloader3.load(new URLRequest("assets/matrix1.swf"));
    addChild(fl_Proloader3);
    fl_Proloader3.x = 0;
    fl_Proloader3.y = 300;
    trace("Matrix1 Load");
}
else
{
    fl_Proloader3.unload();
    removeChild(fl_Proloader3);
    fl_Proloader3 = null;
    trace("Matrix1 UnLoad");
}
fl_ToLoad3 = !fl_ToLoad3;
}

function matrixLoad2(event:MouseEvent): void
{
if (fl_ToLoad4)
{
    fl_Proloader4 = new fl_Proloader4();
    fl_Proloader4.load(new URLRequest("assets/matrix2.swf"));
    addChild(fl_Proloader4);
    fl_Proloader4.x = 0;
    fl_Proloader4.y = 300;
    trace("Matrix2 Load");
}
else
{
    fl_Proloader4.unload();
    removeChild(fl_Proloader4);
    fl_Proloader4 = null;
    trace("Matrix2 UnLoad");
}
fl_ToLoad4 = !fl_ToLoad4;
}


matrix1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, matrixLoad);
matrix2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, matrixLoad2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get your code working, you should avoid some errors like using a variable and a Class with the same name :

```
fl_Proloader3 = new fl_Proloader3();
```

here if you have a Class called `fl_Proloader3` so your instance should have a different name (the same thing for `fl_Proloader4 = new fl_Proloader4();`).

Also, I don't know how did you initialized `fl_ToLoad4` and `fl_ToLoad3`, but normally they should have the `false` value at the beginning because your SWFs are not already been loaded, and in that case your `if` statements should be like this :

```
if (! fl_ToLoad3)
{
    // load the swf
} 
else 
{
    // unload the swf
}
```

but you can even do all that without using `Boolean`s by just using your `Loader` objects, like this :

```
if (! fl_Proloader3)
{
    // load the swf
} 
else 
{
    // unload the swf
}
```

which can give you something like this :

```
var fl_Proloader3:Loader,
    fl_Proloader4:Loader;

function matrixLoad(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    // here we can know that the other swf is loaded or not
    if (fl_Proloader4) {
        trace("Matrix2 is Loaded");
    } else {
        trace("Matrix2 is Unloaded");
    }

    if (! fl_Proloader3) {
        fl_Proloader3 = new Loader();
        fl_Proloader3.load(new URLRequest("assets/matrix1.swf"));
        addChild(fl_Proloader3);
        fl_Proloader3.x = 0;
        fl_Proloader3.y = 300;
    } else {
        fl_Proloader3.unload();
        removeChild(fl_Proloader3);
        fl_Proloader3 = null;
    }
}

function matrixLoad2(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    // here we can know that the other swf is loaded or not
    if (fl_Proloader3) {
        trace("Matrix1 is Loaded");
    } else {
        trace("Matrix1 is Unloaded");
    }

    if (! fl_Proloader4) {
        fl_Proloader4 = new Loader();
        fl_Proloader4.load(new URLRequest("assets/matrix2.swf"));
        addChild(fl_Proloader4);
        fl_Proloader4.x = 0;
        fl_Proloader4.y = 300;
    } else {
        fl_Proloader4.unload();
        removeChild(fl_Proloader4);
        fl_Proloader4 = null;
    }
}

matrix1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, matrixLoad);
matrix2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, matrixLoad2);
```

**Edit :**

An example :

[image]

Hope that can help.

Comment: These were initialized by:

`matrix1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, matrixLoad);`
`matrix2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, matrixLoad2);`

I will restructure as you have above and let you know how it goes. Thank you. Will post back...

Comment: Here is the initialization:

`var container:MovieClip = new MovieClip();`
`addChild(container);`
`container.x = 1050;`
`container.y = 702;`

`var dMatrix:dMatrix_mc = new dMatrix_mc();`
`container.addChild(dMatrix);`

`var nMatrix:nMatrix_mc = new nMatrix_mc();`
`container.addChild(nMatrix);`
`nMatrix.x = 110;`

`container.addChild(nMatrix);`

`var fl_ProLoader3:ProLoader;`
`var fl_ProLoader4:ProLoader;`

`var fl_ToLoad3:Boolean = true;`
`var fl_ToLoad4:Boolean = true;`

Comment: Getting errors initially, I think it may be because I hadn't originally posted my initialization lines (which are now posted). Any thoughts? I do see how you are structuring it and understand how this makes sense. 

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Implicit coercion of a value of type.display:Loader to an unrelated typefl.display:ProLoader-------------------- there are 2 and they point to the `fl_Proloader3 = new Loader();` and `fl_Proloader4 = new Loader();` lines

Comment: @P.T.Fenn You should declare `fl_Proloader3` and `fl_Proloader4` as `Loader` objects and not `ProLoader` ones ...

Comment: we are getting somewhere with that ProLoader/ Loader change you suggested. The `trace("Matrix2 is Unloaded");` is now showing when dMatrix is selected but the SWF is not loading and the same for the nMatrix button.

Comment: @P.T.Fenn You can use `Loader`s or `ProLoader`s but not both (I mean for declaration and initialization). Did you tried my code ? I don't see what's your problem now because my code should work according to your posted one ?

Comment: I did try your code and it is working but the SWF that are being called are not showing. The items that show are in the comments section. They are: `trace("Matrix2 is Unloaded");` and `trace("Matrix1 is loaded");` I have attempted to place the new Loader and URLRequest inside those 'if' statements and this still does not call the swf to the stage. I have changed over all instances from ProLoader to Loader as suggested.

Comment: Using your code above, I get this as a result in the comments window: `Matrix2 is Unloaded` and `Matrix1 is loaded` for each button respectively. I am not sure why the SWF files are not showing on stage though. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: @P.T.Fenn I added a little example, I changed the positions of the `Loader` objects of course ( `fl_Proloader3.x = 50; fl_Proloader3.y = 100;` and `fl_Proloader4.x = 400; fl_Proloader4.y = 100;` ) ... Take a look. I don't know why you have a problem, it's really very easy, add two buttons, and two swf in your assets dir next to your swf and that's all ...

Comment: The problem was on my end. The SWF file name was changed in my original post for secrecy and I failed to change them back... Your code is perfect and has fixed my issue. My apologies for dragging this on. Thank you, thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You can dispatch an custom event whenever the swf unloaded. Then you can listen this event and the other one will be aware of the view&unload structure.

```
function matrixLoad(event:MouseEvent): void
{
    var customEvent:Event = new Event("SomeEventName", true);
    if (fl_ToLoad3)
    {
        fl_Proloader3 = new fl_Proloader3();
        fl_Proloader3.load(new URLRequest("assets/matrix1.swf"));
        addChild(fl_Proloader3);
        fl_Proloader3.x = 0;
        fl_Proloader3.y = 300;
        trace("Matrix1 Load");
    }
    else
    {
        fl_Proloader3.unload();
        dispatchEvent(customEvent);//just after unload
        removeChild(fl_Proloader3);
        fl_Proloader3 = null;
        trace("Matrix1 UnLoad");
    }
    fl_ToLoad3 = !fl_ToLoad3;
}

function SomeTriggerEvent(ref:Event):void
{
    trace("swf unloaded");
}

addEventListener("SomeEventName", SomeTriggerEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [LocalConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html). LocalConnection allows for the communication between two or more SWFs. In this case, you can have your active swf send a message to your other swf and tell it that it is currently in use.

[Here's](https://permadi.com/2009/04/using-localconnection-for-swf-communications-in-actionscript-3/) a great example on how to use LocalConnection. In your case, you can substitute the trace statement in the received message function with whatever you need to do to handle a dormant swf. Also, in your case, right before you unload the swf, you can send a message to your other (or main) swf and tell it that it is about to be unloaded.